# Sorting a matrix by its column without affecting the other columns

Tags: for-loop, matrix, columnsorting

I want to sort my matrix by each column. The matrix has 200 columns. sorting has to be done one column at a time and the order of the other column should not be affected.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Could you show an example and/or tell what programming language and libraries your are using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi sorry, i am using R for this. I have basically simulated some losses using a distribution and now i have to calculate VAR and CVAR on those simulations for which i need to sort the column from worst to best. Would really appreciate some help